# Another exception was thrown: Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-getx

I am using bottom navigation bar which contains global key which i have been intialized in home controller.
I am routing my page like from page1 to page 2 and page 3 and now from page 3 i am routing back to home page then it throws the error below:

ch=false

Another exception was thrown: Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey.

Another exception was thrown: Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey.

Another exception was thrown: Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey.

Comment: can you add your code snippet

Answer (score 3):

Move all the keys and `Flutter` related imports on the widget. It's not recommended to use any UI code inside your logic layer(GetxController). It may seem to you that `Keys and TextEdittingControllers` are logic layer objects, but they are not. They are UI/Flutter layer object.

And always keep in mind that, lifecycles of Flutter and GetX isn't exactly same. So it's always better to use any Flutter `disposable interfaces` (Keys, Controllers and not GetX controllers) in the widget.